# CakePHP 2.2.4: Redirect not Working When Using Component

Tags: cakephp, redirect, controller

It has come to my attention that the redirect controller method is not working part of the time. No message appears when I set debug > 0. I don't echo any code before calling the redirect method so it shouldn't be because of "headers already sent".

Let's take a look at my ArticlesController add action where redirect works in one instance but not in another.

```
public function add($page = null) {
    // Custom component to get if user has required access level
    // of page to write an article. If not, setflash to an error message
    // specific to user's access level and redirect.

    $access_message = $this->CustomPage->AccessMessage(4, $this->viewVars['access']);

    if($access_message){

        // Flash works but redirect does not
        $this->Session->setFlash(__($access_message));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', 'page' => $page));
        // Also tried
        // $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'articles', 'action' => 'index', 'page' => $page), null, true);
    } else
    {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Article->create();
                if ($this->Article->save($this->request->data)) {

                    // BLAH BLAH save post, do other stuff
                    // BLAH BLAH save post, do other stuff

                    // This flash and redirect works
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article has been saved'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', 'id' => $article_id, 'page' => $page));

                    } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                    } // end else if article cannot be saved
        } // if method is post
    } // end if user has access
} // end add action
```

It definitely has something to do with the component but I'm not sure what. Maybe since redirect is called right after the component is used, the "$this" is trying to do the redirect method on the component instead of the controller. I tried $this->Article->redirect and reloading the Article model before the redirect but neither of those worked.

My component code is:

```
public function AccessMessage($required_level, $user_level) {

    if(!$user_level && $this->_View->viewVars['access']){
        $user_level = $this->_View->viewVars['access'];
    }

    if(!$required_level || !$user_level || $user_level != $required_level){
        $accessModel = ClassRegistry::init('Access');
        $access_message = $accessModel->field('access_message', array('Access.id' => $required_level));
     }

      return $access_message;
}
```

**Edit 1:** Ok so I did some digging to find exactly where the problem is stemming from. The USE of the component is not the problem which I thought it was before. If all I have in my component is

```
public function AccessMessage($required_level, $user_level) {

    if(!$user_level && $this->_View->viewVars['access']){
        $user_level = $this->_View->viewVars['access'];
    }

    if(!$required_level || !$user_level || $user_level != $required_level){
        $access_message = 1;
     }

      return $access_message;
}
```

Then it works. The issue is with these two lines which are correctly implemented because they return the value for $access_message I am expecting, but they are interfering with the ability to redirect. Perhaps headers are already sent out?

```
        $accessModel = ClassRegistry::init('Access');
        $access_message = $accessModel->field('access_message', array('Access.id' => $required_level));
```

Please note I have also tried:

```
        $access_message = ClassRegistry::init('Access')->field('access_message', array('Access.id' => $required_level));
```

And

```
        $this->loadModel('Access');
        $access_message = $this->Access->field('access_message', array('Access.id' => $required_level));
```

**Gists:**

> component gist: https://gist.github.com/970a951715205c222348
>
> controller gist: https://gist.github.com/2b90e5af2518a81672fb
>
> access model gist: https://gist.github.com/bhndbrwneyes/f333a93f0a21302d832f

Comment: Are you doing anything in your Component's `_construct()` or any of the callbacks like `initialize()`, `startup()`, etc?

Comment: This looks too specific to your code - how can anyone see or reproduce "the problem" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have space `before/after php Opening/Closing tags in controller and models`. Remove all the closing tags from all controllers and models and any whitespace before opening tags. Then check the result.

Comment: just double checked everything and no I don't :(

Comment: Ok I found it, it was actually a space BEFORE the opening tag of my Access model. I replaced my component code using Class Registry on a different model and it worked fine so I knew the problem had to be within the Access model. I kept looking for spaces around the closing tag but it was at the open tag. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome bowlerae, I have updated the answer also, so that anybody who view this question can get help.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer yet, but at least there are some variables in your code that may not be defined, or errors that can occur:

```
public function AccessMessage($required_level, $user_level) {

    if(!$user_level && $this->_View->viewVars['access']){
        $user_level = $this->_View->viewVars['access'];
    }

    if(!$required_level || !$user_level || $user_level != $required_level){
        $access_message = 1;
    }

    return $access_message;
}
```

- <strike>Variable $access_message will only be defined *if* a user is not allowed to access the page</strike>
- An error may occur if the 'access' viewVar is not set at all

Change it to this:

```
public function AccessMessage($required_level, $user_level) {
    $access_message = 0;

    if(!$user_level && $this->_View->get('access')){
        $user_level = $this->_View->get('access');
    }

    if(!$required_level || !$user_level || $user_level != $required_level){
        $access_message = 1;
    }

    return $access_message;
}
```

[updated] saw you *did* have the $access_message defined on your gist (https://gist.github.com/970a951715205c222348)

However:
This will *not* work

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller', 'ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
```

App::uses() takes two arguments; the 'class' you would like to use and the location it can be found. The line above should be written as:

```
App::uses('Component',     'Controller/Component');
App::uses('Controller',    'Controller');
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
```

But I wonder if ClassRegistry needs to be loaded manually

[update 2] You really have a lot 'weird' things going on in your application, so I wonder if we'll be able to sort that out:

```
public function add($page = null) {
    $access = $this->viewVars['access'];

    if($this->CustomPage->AccessMessage(4, $access)){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__($this->CustomPage->AccessMessage(4, $access)));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', 'page' => $page));
    }

    // ......
}
```

- Where is 'viewVars['access']' set?
- You're passing 'viewVars['access']' as the second parameter ($user_level) to AccessMessage(), but *inside* AccessMessage() you're trying to use the same viewVar again if the parameter '$user_level' was not set?
- $this->CustomPage->AccessMessage() is called *twice* once to check if it returned anything, then to *use* it. Not very efficient

.

```
public function add($page = null) {
    // Where does is $this->viewVars['access'] come from? Where is it set?
    $access  = empty($this->viewVars['access'])? null : $this->viewVars['access'];
    $message = $this->CustomPage->AccessMessage(4, $access);

    if ($message) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__($message));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', 'page' => $page));
    }

    // ......
}
```

On a further note. **you're redirecting the user only if a 'message' was found and not empty, NOT based on the current users permissions**, you might consider splitting the two;

In your component:

```
public function HasAccessLevel($required_level, $user_level) {
    if(!$user_level || $user_level != $required_level){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public function AccessMessage($required_level) {
    return ClassRegistry::init('Access')->field('access_message', array('Access.id' => $required_level));
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function add($page = null) {
    // Where does is $this->viewVars['access'] come from? Where is it set?
    $access  = empty($this->viewVars['access'])? null : $this->viewVars['access'];

    if($this->CustomPage->HasAccessLevel(4, $access)){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__($this->CustomPage->AccessMessage(4)));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', 'page' => $page));
    }

    // ......
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions. Voting up, however my issue is not resolved. I changed the app:uses to the three separate lines. Access var is defined in AppController, I also got ride of the check for the access variable in the component since it was already being passed by the ArticlesController. Split the AccessMessage function into 2 separate functions for more efficiency and used in ArticlesController as instructed but still no redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Cake 2: At the top of the component: add

```
  public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
        $this->Controller = $controller;
    }
```

inside the function you can redirect like so:

```
$this->Controller->redirect(array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect is called, but you are not redirected I guess you have some permission check in your `index()` action that prevents the access. Can you confirm or post the whole controller code?

Comment: I don't have a permission check in my index(). authAllow allows index() in all controllers. my index() in my articles controller only displays a list of all the articles where page_id = $page. I am able to successfully redirect to the index() when in view(), the id for the article does not exist.

Comment: ok, then what exactly means - "Redirect not working"? Do you see white screen, or are you still in the view for `Articles/add`? And does the redirect works if you remove the `CustomPage` component and comment out the call `$access_message = $this->CustomPage->AccessMessage(4, $this->viewVars['access']);`? If so, I agree with penguin egg, that it looks like you have something in component's or app callback, `beforeRedirect` maybe?

Comment: Yes to everything you said. White screen still on add() view. Works if I comment out the use of the component or if I comment out the "return $access_message" in the actual component itself. But I am not using any callbacks.

Comment: So it's not really the use of the component itself, but the return of $access_message.

Comment: ok, thanks for update. What exactly do you have in `$access_message` (when you do `var_dump()` or `debug()`)? It might cause error when passing to translation function `__()`. Besides in your component method, there is no default value of `$access_message` so if the condition is not met, you will get PHP notice...

Comment: Please see my edit 1. When !$access_message, the user is able to view the add() action's view file as expected. If I don't try to redirect and simply echo or print the access_message, then I get the correct value. The issue is not with $access_message itself but the initializing the Access model and doing a field find on it. But that is the whole point of my component so I want it to work and then redirect.

Comment: Mm, I don't see any problem in those `field()` calls (however `$this->loadModel()` works only in controller)... It seems you have some other problem, but it's not possible to see from the snippets. If you have in your *app/Config/core.php* `Configure::write('debug', 2);` you should be able to get error reporting. If still nothing, you need to post whole code for the component and the controller. Use gist or similar and post a link to it

Comment: please see newest edit with links to gists. Thanks for all your time and consideration.

Comment: There is another reason for notice: `$this->_View` inside component is not defined. If you need to access `viewVars`, you should save the reference to controller in `initialize()` or `startup()` methods. The rest might not cause errors, but I would recommend reading cookbook on [components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html). Next: why in controller you have `$this->Auth->allow('topic', 'edit', 'add', 'delete');`, but not for index action? However, if you're testing and you are not logged in, you are redirected to login url, so that's not it... Did any of this helped?

Comment: I commented out the $this->_View lines and I had the same issue so this isn't the cause of the problem. Also, index is allowed in my AppController's Auth->allow. Normally I would not allow guests to add, edit or delete articles but I allowed it in my articles controller just for testing so I didn't have to keep logging in just to post a test article. Again, the issue is with the lines    

`$accessModel = ClassRegistry::init('Access');

$access_message = $accessModel->field('access_message', array('Access.id' => $required_level));`

Comment: ok, then can be problem in your `Access` model? Maybe good idea to post code of this model as well. Or just make sure you have in DB table `accesses` or that you define `useTable` model property. Also try `App::uses('Access', 'Model');` before you call `ClassRegistry::init()`. And maybe even check if it works with calling `$accessModel->findById($required_level, array('access_message'))`... I really wonder what is the problem for you;)

Comment: added an Access model gist. There is no issue when doing `$access_message = $accessModel->field('access_message', array('Access.id' => $required_level));` Only once it redirects.